# Regular expression to match all words ending with and containing three 'e's

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that **matches all words so that the only vowel is e and there are exactly three e's in the word**, am writing this in python. I tried writing

```
(?= e){3}[^aiou]*
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: @Nathon if I'm thinking clearly: (?= ...) creates a positive look-ahead assertion, so it's "0 or more characters that are either not vowels or e, such that the first 3 characters are e's". Which... actually amounts to the same thing. :) But the [^aiou] match looks at the e's as well, which happen to match, since 'e' is not a non-e vowel. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want three e's, such that the stuff in between consists of non-vowels. You want a word, i.e. stuff that has a word boundary on either side.

Thus: a word boundary, zero or more non-vowels, an e, zero or more non-vowels, an e, zero or more non-vowels, an e, zero or more non-vowels, and a word boundary. But we can simplify that by grouping up the repeated pattern: a word boundary, three times: (zero or more non-vowels, an e), zero or more non-vowels, and a word boundary.

In regex-speak: `\b(?:[^aeiou]*e){3}[^aeiou]*\b`.

Comment: @larsmans: It would be more elegant if it didn’t repeat the "non-vowel" thing.  And it would be more correct if it included "y". :)

Comment: Handling "y" is quite difficult in simple RE frameworks such those of Python.

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off testing the two parts seperately.
First use:

```
^[^aiou]*$
```

Then use:

```
^([^e]*e[^e]*){3}$
```

Comment: By the same logic I applied, the second one can be refactored as `^(?:[^e]*e){3}[^e]*$` (note the use of non-grouping parenthesis), which some might find more elegant as `^(?:.*?e){3}.*?$`. Although anchoring to the beginning and end of the string might not be the best idea if we want to match words. Then again, if we **do** want to match the whole string, then instead of *matching* like that, we can *search* for `(?:e.*?){2}e` - a common refactoring: use searching to eliminate `^.*?` at the beginning and/or `.*?$` at the end. Which, in turn, might be better as just `e.*?e.*?e`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`\s[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*e[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*e[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*e[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*\s`

http://rubular.com

Comment: If we insist that "words" can only contain letters of the alphabet, sure. (Only lowercase ones, at that, unless we enable case-insensitive matching.)

Comment: True... By the time i finished typing this, 3 other answers were up. Though they also target only lowercase [aiou]

Comment: yes, to be fair I shouldn't pick on case-(in)sensitivity when I didn't address it myself ;)

Comment: i actually thought of that but as Karl already said, a word may contain symbols as well as letters so it would be alot of trouble to go over every symbol/number etc... but thanks anyways man =D

Comment: Not a good idea to enumerate the things you do want instead of those do *not* want.  For example, you forgot ß.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only working in ASCII, I would suggest this solution:

```
(?i)(?=^[^aiouy]*$)^(?:[^e]*e){3}[^e]*$
```

Here’s a demo of that pattern, randomly selecting ten matching words from the `dict` list:

```
% perl -ne 'print if /(?i)(?=^[^aiouy]*$)^(?:[^e]*e){3}[^e]*$/' /usr/share/dict/words | 
  perl -e '@a = <>; print splice(@a, rand @a, 1) for 1..10'
centgener
geezer
sceptered
gentlemens
neckweed
whenceeer
tenderer
scentlessness
beswelter
entrenchment
```

Yes, my demo uses Perl, but the pattern should be just fine in Python as well. I’m just not so nimble whipping off one-liners in Python as I am in Perl. :)